# Difference between Past continuous and Past perfect continuous

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-continuous, past-perfect-continuous

In these following sentences, which one is grammatically correct?

> 1. They were playing football since 10 o'clock.
> 2. They had been playing football since 10 o'clock.

According to this reference [link](http://www.englishkitab.com/en/Essential_Grammar/Tenses/Past_Perfect_Continuous_Tense.html):

> Past Perfect Continuous Tense is used to express a continued or
>   ongoing action that started in past and is continued until sometime in
>   past. There will always a time reference like – for a few days, for
>   ten months, for 2 years, since Wednesday, since 2011, since January
>   etc. **If there is no time reference, then it is not a Past perfect
>   continuous tense. Without time reference, it is Past Continuous Tense.**

But I saw the following example, which has used with time reference.

[image: ppc]

So, I am confused between past continuous and past perfect continuous. Please someone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The highlighted sentence is from where? It's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the sentence is wrong, it should either be "they had been playing football since 10 o'clock, meaning they started at ten and continued until a later time, or "they were playing football at ten" meaning at ten they were in the middle of the game. I think it is a mistake because the other sentences are all examples of the past perfect continuous.