# "When I worked" and "when I was working" after "used to be"

Tags: tense, past-simple, past-continuous, used-to

I have a question about using "when I did ..." and "when I was doing ..." in a certain sentence.

When you are talking about a currently busy store that you worked at several years ago, are both of these sentences appropriate?

> Business used to be slower when I **worked** at the store.
>
> Business used to be slower when I **was working** at the store.

I think both "when I worked ..." and "when I was working ..." are fine if the sentence begins with "Business was slower ..." but I don't know if they are fine when you use "used to be" in the sentence instead of "was."

Comment: Yes, both your sentences are fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Past continuous and Past perfect continuous](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/226293/difference-between-past-continuous-and-past-perfect-continuous)

Comment: The question is about **past continuous** versus **simple past**, not past perfect continuous, so unlikely

Comment: @Riolku The question seems different from mine (my question wasn't about past perfect continuous). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @ColleenV I don't think that quite answers my question (the question isn't about the phrase "used to"), but it did help my understanding of past continuous. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I think that *on average* it would be stylistically weak to use a past *continuous* verb form after "used to be" (as an alternative to using Simple Past). Purely because "used to be" tends to place greater "distance" between speaker and the past circumstances/actions being referenced (so it's often used when *contrasting* the past with the present). On the other hand, the past *continuous* generally has the ***opposite*** effect, because speaker is often trying to "immerse" his audience in some past activity or circumstance - effectively "merging" past into present. But syntactically it's fine